# MKMapView hides all controls on the view

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview, mapkit

I have added UIButton, UITextField and MKMapView in UIViewController. I bind all controls to properties. But when I run application there is no button and textField, only map. I have navigation controller and I was thinking that it hides controls but no. Is there any additional option that must be set when adding more controls with MKMapView in one View?
And I forgot to tell. In UITextField I have hardcoded value ("London") and in set location on map I get value from that UITextField and it works. So field is somewhere on the screen but it seams that map hides it somehow.
But, if I in view editor make map smaller it somehow fine. But why I must make it so small in editor to be fine in run mode?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should bring your UIButton, UITextField with

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:UIView]
```

to the front.